# getting JSON data to PHP

Tags: php, html, json, post

I have a trouble with JSON.
I have this pice of code from JS:

```
type: "POST",
url: '/form.php',
data: JSON.stringify(this.getValues()),
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function(data){
    that.afterSubmit();
},
```

After post I getiing this:

```
[{"role":"name","label":"Name","value":"ttere"},{"role":"phone","label":"Phone","value":"(454) 564-56-45"}]
```

It's ok, but I can't get this params to php file:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['Object']);
$response = 'Get params '.count($data).'\n';
foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
    $response .= 'Par: '.$key.'; Val: '.$value.'\n';
}
echo $response;
```

Comment: I did not get what are you trying to do here? Are you trying to create json, append it to response message and then send it back?

Comment: from the looks of it, trying to get the json data he receives in a client side script to appear in the server side script. probably so he can save it.

Comment: Where are that JSON data in your question from? Are they from `$data` variable?

Comment: I don't think he is trying to save it because, if he is trying to save the JSON (I guess to DB), then why is he appending it to (string) $response variable?

If you want to append a new string to your json, just do add it to $data, reencode it as JSON and send it.

But it's just a guess.

Answer (score -3):

make a hidden input field for html and use your javascript to update the value of that field and then post the form. i.e.:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form id="after-i-get-json-stuff" method="post">
      <input id="update-this" type="hidden" name="Object" value="" />
    </form>
    <script>
      //HOWEVER YOU GET YOUR JSON DATA
      $('#update-this').val(data);
      $('#after-i-get-json-stuff').submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html
```